# Chrome Extension - Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Google Chrome extension and calling a function by clicking a button.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="Search" id="inputText">
      <button type="submit" class="button" id="submitButton"></button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=script.js></script>
</body>
```

**script.js**

```
submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton")
if (submitButton) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    submitButton.addEventListener("click", submit);
  });
}
...
function submit() {
...
}
```

**Output**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: submitButton is not defined
```

Comment: Most likely, this JS code is in implied strict mode. Have you _declared_ `submitButton`? You should write `const submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");`.

Comment: You are assigning `submitButton` a reference to a dom element that might not exist if you are loading your script in the `head` of your `HTML` document. Load your script right before the closing `body` tag and that should solve your issue or declare and assign `submitButton` when `DOMContentLoaded ` has fired. Also, globals are bad... You should declare your `submitButton` variable with either the `var` or `const` keyword so it's scoped to the `function` or `block` it's defined in, depending.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, 1. No need for DOMContentLoaded at all since your script already runs at the end of HTML, 2. The popup page isn't a web server so you can't submit forms without external action as it just reloads the popup; either don't use forms or cancel the submit event using preventDefault() and 3. Use devtools debugger which is separate for the popup: right-click it, click "inspect".